# Storing an object-tree or flat-objects with references as JSON within localStorage

Tags: json, local-storage, storage, javascript-objects

Suppose I have two JSON objects named Car and Wheel. Car has a collection of Wheel, the rest are primitive-type properties.

Car:

- Name
- Speed
- Wheels

Wheel:

- Thickness
- Friction

Now if I want to save this car with localStorage I have two options.

1. I can serialize the car object including its wheels and use the name of the car as key within localStorage (saving the whole object-tree).
2. I can also save the car, excluding the wheels. Save the wheels separately and give the wheels an Id-property. Then make a reference from Car to a collection of wheel-ids (making the object-tree flat).

The downside I see in the first solution is that if I rename the wheels property in-code, I will lose previously stored data, while referencing and retrieving the separate wheels by Id will not. On the other hand the second solution is getting more like a Relational Database instead of Object-Oriented where JSON is meant for.

My question is: what can I use best for this kind of storage and why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a part of both solutions and make a difference, where to use which option:

1. Save them to the localStorage as separated objects (the second option) and keep only a reference in the car object, so you will keep them DRY. You can then rename the property in-code without loosing a reference and in the future. You can also still access only wheels for some future purpose in a more semantic way.
2. Make an abstraction in your code, where you serialize and deserialize the both objects and connect them there (as you wanted in the first solution). So JSON will be still clean and you will get all the advantages of the connected solution.

Unfortunately, as you certainly know, there is no the best option. It depends very on your **intuition** and **prediction of the future** of your data. Abstraction can help you with that, because most of the time, **when you can refactor something later on, you probably will**.

Answer (score 0):

I have also thought about this, and tested the performance difference between storing a large list and storing the list items separately. I think this is enough to provide some suggestions for latecomers.

From a performance perspective, unless you always know the keys of localStorage and only need a few of items at a time, serializing and storing the entire object tree is often 10x faster.

Considering that the storage capacity of localStorage is small, and flat-objects require some additional structure, the content that flat-objects can store will actually become less. Flat-objects seems to save storage space by sharing items, but the same thing can be done in a single object, just see how people use Redux.

In addition, flat-objects also need to overcome the risk of "reference breaking"(from users), so a garbage collection function is also needed.

Conclusion: Store the entire object. If you insist on storing flat-objects, even IndexedDB will be better.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Do you have any benchmarks on this?